# Select Func in Lambda Expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, lambda

Hi Experts
I want to use Lambda Expression and write this code:

```
Func<Regions, SelectAllRegion> Select = r => new {r.RegionID,r.RegionDescription};
        clsr.SelectAll<SelectAllRegion>(Select);
```

but I does not works.It raise this Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'SelectAllRegion'
```

How should I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
Func<Regions, SelectAllRegion> Select = r => new SelectAllRegion {
                                      RegionID = r.RegionID,
                                      RegionDescription = r.RegionDescription };
```

That's assuming you've *got* a suitable `SelectAllRegion` class. The lambda expression you posted converts a a `Regions` into an anonymous type - which is always the result of `new { ... }`. That can only (usefully) be used in the context of type inference, rather than a simple variable declaration as you've got here.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line returns an anonymous type.  You want to return a `SelectAllRegion` - something like this:

```
Func<Regions, SelectAllRegion> Select = r => new SelectAllRegion()
    {RegionID = r.RegionID, RegionDescription = r.RegionDescription};
```